Who - if anyone - predicted the emission of gamma rays from jetted active galaxies? An historiographical inquiry
We know that the relativistic electrons that produce synchrotron radiation in the jets of active galaxies also produce gamma radiation via the inverse Compton mechanism (in the most simple scenario scattering their own synchrotron photons). I was wondering if someone had made such a claim explicitly in a paper before gamma rays from jetted AGN were discovered.
I searched as hard as I could on early speculations (say 1950s to 1980s) about gamma ray emission from AGN, but I could find none. I will try to resume my bibliographic search.
From the theoretical side, already in the 70s the processes for producing gamma rays are well known, we can find in the illustrious Blumenthal & Gould review (1970), computation of inverse Compton spectra (that should inevitably be in gamma rays, considering certain photon targets). I also found in “Cosmic Gamma rays” by Stecker (1971), the claim that “No attempt is made here to list and discuss these observational attempts in detail; such listings may be found in recent reviews. Neither is it the author's intention to construct crude models for possible point sources of cosmic y-rays. The emphasis here is on a discussion of the basic gamma-ray production processes themselves”. Not only the processes producing cosmic gamma rays are established, astrophysicists are even concerned with other effects such as absorption in gamma-gamma to pair production that could impede us detecting them (see Jelley, 1966). It is also considered how cooling via inverse Compton could affect radio spectra (Kellerman, 1969), without explicitly mentioning that the side effect of this cooling is the production of gamma rays (I guess it was not the focus of the paper). The only thing coming close to what I want, i.e. a real “crude model” to use Stecker’s words, is "Gamma Rays Sources - Black Holes?" By Karakula et al. (1983), where they speculate that the gamma ray emission might come from $\pi_0$ produced by inelastic collisions of protons accelerated (heated up) in the accretion disk. This is not a real forecast though, since 3C273 had already been detected by COS B in 1978, and they even attempted to model its spectrum. Incidentally, in the 3C273 discovery paper they do not make any reference to gamma-ray emission models for AGN, which is something I would have expected in such a seminal paper (i.e. I was expecting to read something on the lines of “many models predict gamma-ray emission from AGN, but so far no successful detection of cosmic gamma rays has been possible”). I started to search from the experimental side then, I figured that in some papers describing the prospects for EGRET observations they should reference some predictions for AGN, and indeed in Kanbach et al. (1988) some forecasts on the discrete extragalactic sources detectable by EGRET are made, but just extrapolating their X-ray spectra and scaling the flux according to that of 3C 273, which was the only AGN detected by then, no mention of theoretical models. In a recent review by the same author I found references to early attempts (before any detection) to explicitly predict the flux of gamma-ray sources, but unfortunately only for Crab and the Galactic Centre (see Sec. 2 of Kanbach, 2019).
To my knowledge Roger Blandford and Martin Rees are those who paved the way towards our current understanding of the jet models. Yet, I could not find in their most influential papers any suggestion that the relativistic electrons producing the synchrotron radiation we see in radio should also produce gamma rays. I am familiar with the papers from Dermer and Ghisellini on the gamma ray emission of blazars. But those were written in the 90s, when gamma rays from AGN were already an established fact.
Does anyone have further sources? Does someone who made this statement explicitly exist, or - as with many things in science and astrophysics in particular - the idea consolidated from several small contributions from different people and at a certain point simply established itself?
P.S. cross-posted on physics stack exchange.
